# C-Server : Ncat: Connection reset by peer

Tags: c

**Problem:**

Soon as I add these two lines to my server..

```
fff = popen(ccc, "r");
pclose(fff);
```

I get this "connection reset by peer" when testing it via netcat.

```
echo test | nc <ip> <port>
   <response>
Ncat: Connection reset by peer.
```

without those 2 lines..

```
echo test | nc <ip> <port>
    <response>
```

smooth. no problem.

What is the proper solution ?

**FULL CODE:**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <netdb.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <err.h>
#include <string.h>


FILE * fff;
char * ooo = "HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\n\r\n aa \r\n";
char * ppp = "/10/web";
char iip [15];


int main()
{
  int one = 1, client_fd;
  struct sockaddr_in svr_addr, cli_addr;
  socklen_t sin_len = sizeof(cli_addr);

  int sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
  if (sock < 0)
    err(1, "can't open socket");

  setsockopt(sock, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, &one, sizeof(int));

  int port = 50;
  svr_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
  svr_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
  svr_addr.sin_port = htons(port);

  if (bind(sock, (struct sockaddr *) &svr_addr, sizeof(svr_addr)) == -1) {
    close(sock);
    err(1, "Can't bind");
  }

  listen(sock, 5);
  while (1) {
    client_fd = accept(sock, (struct sockaddr *) &cli_addr, &sin_len);
    snprintf(iip, 15, "%s", inet_ntoa(cli_addr.sin_addr));

    char * ccc;
    asprintf(&ccc, "%s %s", ppp, iip);
    fff = popen(ccc, "r");
    pclose(fff);

    printf(ccc);
    printf("\n");
    printf("connection.. \n");

    write(client_fd, ooo, strlen(ooo));
    close(client_fd);
  }
}
```

incase it matters.. this is the file ( /10/web )

```
#!/bin/sh
printf 'test';
echo 'uuuuuu';
```

Comment: I suggest you check if `popen` actually succeeds, and `fff` is not a null pointer.

Comment: Also, check (from a shell) that you actually *can* execute `/10/web`.

Comment: @Some programmer dude, How can I check it ?

Comment: Read the [man page](https://linux.die.net/man/3/popen).

Comment: `if (fff == NULL)`?

Comment: @Some programmer dude, executes fine : `/10/web
testuuuuuu`

Comment: `if (fff == NULL){
    printf("null");
    }else{
    printf("not null");
    }`   returns "not null"

Comment: `char inn [500];` + `size_t bytesRead = read(client_fd,inn,500);` seems to have solved the problem but I am not sure why it solves the problem. perhaps it simply makes it wait a little more before it closes the connection on the client ? How about do not close the connection on the client until you are finished opening the file.. reading it.. processing the commands.. etc.. ?

Comment: The command that closes the connection on the client `close(client_fd);` is all the way down below everything. so why does it close the connectio on the client if opening the file.. reading.. processing commands is not yet a done job ?. also why is the solution mentioned in above comment. actually work. but perhaps it is simply like a "sleep command" ? ( get busy reading incoming data for a few seconds ).. if that is the case.. this means in the future I can experince problems again when my file becomes bigger to read.

Comment: What would have made sense to me is if somebody said "you have to make it wait until reading file is complete and so on.. " rather than "you have to read the incoming data ".. very puzzling logic that does not corolate with everyday common sense.

Answer (score 0):

"Connection reset" means that the server closed the connection without having read the data sent by the client. Given that you don't read from client_fd, it is what you should expect. To fix, make sure you read what the client sends.

Comment: I added this to top: `char inn [500];` and this to under **client_fd** `size_t bytesRead = read(client_fd,inn,500);` but how do I determine how much I should be reading ? perhaps the general stuff the web browsers usually send ? which should be no more than 300 or so characters ?

Comment: @D0RV4 If you want to process HTTP requests, you need to *learn* [the Hypertext Transfer Protocol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypertext_Transfer_Protocol). Like being able to detect when the header ends and the data begins, which is well-specified in the RFCs.

Comment: It seems strange. Server has to get busy reading incoming data in order to open and close an external file ? really confused here. why does it have to read incoming data. isnt it's only job to simply respond to the client somehow ?

Comment: it is actually responding to the client but I suppose without waiting for the file to be opened. read. processed by commands.. etc.. so to solve this dilema we trick it into not closing the connection by reading lots of incoming data ?

Comment: The server must read the request made to it. If it didn't, how would it know how to respond to the client?

Answer (score 0):

`popen` will give error "streams are currently open in the calling process". I suggest you check two line:

```
fff = popen(ccc, "r");
if (fp == NULL)

status=pclose(fff);
if (status == -1) 
/* Error reported by pclose() */
.
.
```

hope it helps